# CES aggregator for intermediates with heterogeneous productivity

Tags: production-function, productivity, cobb-douglas, aggregate-production, ces-function

I'm following Atkeson, Burstein (2019 JPE), and cannot understand the aggregation result.

There is measure $M(z)$ of firms with productivity $z$, with production function
$$
y(z) = z k(z)^\alpha l(z)^{1-\alpha}
$$
Aggregate output is
$$
Y = \left[ \sum_z y(z)^{\frac{\rho-1}{\rho}} M(z) \right]^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}}
$$
Assuming that markup is constant across firms and factor markets are competitive, they get the result
$$
Y = Z K^\alpha L^{1-\alpha}
$$
where $Z = \left[ \sum_z z^{\rho-1} M(z) \right]^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}}$, $K = \sum_z k(z) M(z)$ and $L = \sum_z l(z) M(z)$.

I don't quite understand this jump. Following the usual steps for intermediate goods, I can derive the marginal cost and prices for each firm. They are dependent on $z$, so I can't simply apply the trick that all firms behave in the same way. What I do get is $PZ = p(z) z$ and $y(z)=(z/Z)^\rho Y$. Now I'm lost which way to proceed.